# Responsive website background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have built this background as part of my website design as shown in this [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gavinwynne/6912713223/) with 3 slices (div id top, middle and bottom).

Is it possible to make this responsive? I have seen examples but this is for one large image:
[example 1](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/)
[example 2](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: I am currently using the skeleton boilerplate if that is of any help

Comment: Your flickr image is set to private...

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a simple solution which is to use media queries so when the screen reduces ie 959 / 768 / 767 / 480 / 479 you load in a smaller slice of the graphic. works fine, just need to make sure I keep the file sizes low.